# How can I set the value of the JProgressBar as a reference from another class?

Tags: java, swing

I currently am in the process of coding a little game where there are progress bars that take the values of variables from a different class.
The progress bar goes from 0 to 500, different methods can be called to alter the value of the variable the progress bar is measuring.

```
happyBar = new JProgressBar();
        happyBar.setMinimum(0);
        happyBar.setMaximum(500);
        happyBar.setValue(cat.getHappy());
        happyBar.repaint();
        happyLabel = new JLabel("Happy");
        happyLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
```

The cat.getHappy() that I am referencing seems to pull up an error. 
The method is visible as I added this line of code:

```
public static Cat cat;
```

Does anyone have any ideas like, why I cannot update the JProgressBar by having to take cat.getHappy as its current value?

Full Code:

Interface Class:

```
import java.awt.color.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cat_Interface  {

private JFrame catWindow;
private JPanel topPanel, leftPanel, rightPanel, bottomPanel, allPanels, playPanel, sleepPanel, huntPanel, feedPanel, cleanPanel, walkPanel, drinkPanel;
private JLabel catLabel, happyLabel, hungryLabel, energyLabel, hygieneLabel, weightLabel, thirstLabel, picLabel;
private JButton play, sleep, feed, hunt, clean, walk, drink;
private JProgressBar happyBar, hungryBar, energyBar, thirstBar, weightBar, hygieneBar;
private JTextArea catText;
private JProgressBar happy, hungry, energy, thirst, weight, hygiene;
private int interval;
private Timer timer;


    public Cat_Interface(Cat cat) {
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        allPanels = new JPanel();

        allPanels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(allPanels, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));


        play = new JButton("Play");
        sleep = new JButton("Sleep");
        feed = new JButton("Feed");
        hunt = new JButton("Hunt");
        clean = new JButton("Clean");
        walk = new JButton("Walk");
        drink = new JButton("Drink");
        bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(25,25,25, 25));
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 50, 10));
        bottomPanel.add(play);
        bottomPanel.add(sleep);
        bottomPanel.add(feed);
        bottomPanel.add(hunt);
        bottomPanel.add(clean);
        bottomPanel.add(walk);
        bottomPanel.add(drink);

        leftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());     
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/cat_test_picture.svg");
            leftPanel.add(new JLabel(image));
            leftPanel.setVisible(true);



        rightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        rightPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        happyBar = new JProgressBar();
        happyBar.setMinimum(0);
        happyBar.setMaximum(500);
        //happyBar.setValue(cat.getHappy());
        happyBar.repaint();
        happyLabel = new JLabel("Happy");
        happyLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        hungryBar = new JProgressBar(0,500);
        hungryLabel = new JLabel("Hungry");
        hungryBar.repaint();
        hungryLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        energyBar = new JProgressBar(0,500);
        energyLabel = new JLabel("Energy");
        energyBar.repaint();
        energyLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        hygieneBar = new JProgressBar(0,500);
        hygieneBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        hygieneLabel = new JLabel("Hygiene");
        hygieneBar.repaint();
        hygieneLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        thirstBar = new JProgressBar(0,500);
        thirstLabel = new JLabel("Thirst");
        thirstBar.repaint();
        thirstLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        weightBar = new JProgressBar(0,500);
        weightLabel = new JLabel("Weight");
        weightBar.repaint();
        weightLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        rightPanel.add(happyBar);
        rightPanel.add(happyLabel);
        happyLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        happyBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5, 5);

        rightPanel.add(hungryBar);
        rightPanel.add(hungryLabel);
        hungryLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        hungryBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5, 5);

        rightPanel.add(energyBar);
        rightPanel.add(energyLabel);
        energyLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        energyBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5,5);



        rightPanel.add(hygieneBar);
        rightPanel.add(hygieneLabel);
        hygieneLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        hygieneBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5, 5);

        rightPanel.add(thirstBar);
        rightPanel.add(thirstLabel);
        thirstLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        thirstBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5, 5);

        rightPanel.add(weightBar);
        rightPanel.add(weightLabel);
        weightLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        weightBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5, 5);

        allPanels.add(topPanel);
        allPanels.add(leftPanel);
        allPanels.add(bottomPanel);
        allPanels.add(rightPanel);

        catWindow = new JFrame();
        catWindow.setTitle("Tamagotchi Game: Cat");
        catWindow.setSize(550,300);
        catWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        catWindow.setVisible(true);
        catWindow.add(allPanels);

        catWindow.getContentPane().add(leftPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        catWindow.getContentPane().add(rightPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        catWindow.getContentPane().add(bottomPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //catWindow.getContentPane().add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }

public JButton getPlayButton() {
    return play;
}

public JButton getSleepButton() {
    return sleep;
}

public JButton getFeedButton() {
    return feed;
}

public JButton getHuntButton() {
    return hunt;
}

public JButton getWalkButton() {
    return walk;
}

public JButton getDrinkButton() {
    return drink;
}

public JButton getCleanButton() {
    return clean;
}

public JPanel getPanels() {
    return allPanels;
}
```

}

Cat Class:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

// my own pet class for the cat animal I chose.
public class Cat extends Animal {

Cat_Interface cat = new Cat_Interface(this);
private long tDelta, tEnd; 
private long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
private String furColour, eyeColour;
public int whiskerLength, petDay, petMonth, petYear, ageInYears, ageInMonths,    ageInDays;


    public Cat(String aName, Gender aGender ,String aTrait,String aAgeEffect, DateOfBirth aDateOfBirth,int aWeight, int aPetDay, int aPetMonth, int aPetYear, int aWhiskerLength, String aFurColour, String aEyeColour){

    super(aName, aGender , aTrait,  aWeight, aDateOfBirth,  aAgeEffect);
    petDay = aPetDay;
    petMonth = aPetMonth;
    petYear = aPetYear;
    whiskerLength = aWhiskerLength;
    furColour = aFurColour;
    eyeColour = aEyeColour;
    if (super.getHungry() <=0) {
        Death();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reason:\nYou didn't feed it enough.");
    }
    if (super.getEnergy() <=0) {
        super.passOut();
    }
    if (super.getWeight() >=100) {
        Death();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reason:\nIt was too heavy.");
    }
}
// getters
public String getFurColour() {
    return furColour;
}

public int getWhiskerLength() {
    return whiskerLength;
}

public String getEyeColour() {
    return eyeColour;
}
// setters
public void setFurColour(String aFurColour) {
    furColour = aFurColour;
}

public void setWhiskerLength(int aWhiskerLength) {
    whiskerLength = aWhiskerLength;
}

public void setEyeColour(String aEyeColour) {
    eyeColour = aEyeColour;
}
//custom methods
public void hunt() {
    //my custom method for the cat. This enables the cat to hunt for food when    it is too hungry.
    super.setHappy(super.getHappy() - 10);
    super.setEnergy(super.getEnergy() - 20);
    super.setHungry(super.getHungry() + 30);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, super.getName() + " has hunted and consumed some food. \nFeed " +super.getName() + " more in the future so he doesn't have to do this.");


}

public void cleanSelf() {
// my custom method for the cat. Cats clean themselves and become happier and , obviously, cleaner as a result.
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, super.getName() + " has cleaned itself as you have not cleaned it in a while.");
    super.setHygiene(super.getHygiene() + 20);
    super.setHappy(super.getHappy() + 10);



}

//overridden methods from the animal class
@Override
//method to feed the cat, overriding the feed method from the animal class.
public void feed() {
    if (super.getHungry() > 50) {
        super.setHungry(super.getHungry() + 60);
        super.setWeight(super.getWeight() + 5);
        super.setEnergy(super.getEnergy() + 20);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have fed " + super.getName());
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot feed " + super.getName() + " as they are not hungry. \nWait for the hungriness to fall below 50.");
    }
}
@Override
public void clean() {
    super.setHygiene(super.getHygiene() + 30);
    super.setHappy(super.getHappy() - 20);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have cleaned " + super.getName());
}

@Override
public void play() {
    if (super.getEnergy() >= 50 ) {
        super.setHappy(super.getHappy() + 60);
        super.setEnergy(super.getEnergy() - 40);
        super.setHungry(super.getHungry() - 50);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have played with " + super.getName() + " and they are happy.");
                                    } else {
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must let " + super.getName() + " rest before you can play with them." + "\nThe energy level must be above 50 to play.");
                                    }
    }   
@Override
public void sleep() {
    if (super.getEnergy() <= 120) {
        super.setHappy(super.getHappy() + 30);
        super.setHungry(super.getHungry() - 50);
        super.setEnergy(super.getEnergy() + 50);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have put " + super.getName() + " to sleep.");

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot put " + super.getName() + " to sleep until their energy is below 120." + "\nPlay with them more to decrease the energy level.");
    }

}

@Override
public void passOut() {
    super.setHappy(super.getHappy() - 30);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, super.getName() + " has passed out due to being too tired.");
}
// A method that when called will produce a pop up window with the cat's stats.
public void showStats() {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name: " + super.getName()+ "\nAge: " + findAgeInYears() + " years, " + findAgeInMonths() + " months and " + findAgeInDays() + " days old." +
    "\nTrait:  " + super.getTrait() + "\nHungry: " + super.getHungry() + "\nEnergy: " + super.getEnergy() +
"\nHappy: " + super.getHappy() + "\nHygiene: " + super.getHygiene() + "\nWeight: " + super.getWeight() + "\nThirst: " + super.getThirst() + "\nTime spent together: " + getTimeSpent() +" seconds");
}
// A method that allows you to take the cat on a walk.
public void walk() {
    if (super.getEnergy() >= 50) {
    super.setHappy(super.getHappy() + 60);
    super.setEnergy(super.getEnergy() - 40);
    super.setHungry(super.getHungry() - 10);
    super.setHygiene(super.getHygiene() - 30);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have taken " + super.getName() + " for a walk.");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The energy must be above 40 for " + super.getName() + " to be able to go for a walk.");
}

    }
// This method will kill the cat when certain stats are reached eg hungry <= 0
@Override
public void Death() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, super.getName() + " has died.\nLook after your pets in the future.");
    System.exit(5);
}
//This method will calculate the time spent with the cat.
public double getTimeSpent() {
    tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
    double elapsedSeconds = tDelta / 1000.0;
    return elapsedSeconds;

}
@Override
public void drink() {
    super.setThirst(super.getThirst() + 50);
}

@Override
public void runAway() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, super.getName() + " has run away. Take better care of them in the future.");
    System.exit(5);
}
/**
 * This handy method findAgeInYears() uses a gregorian calendar to give me the value for      the age of the animal in years. It uses the aPetMonth variable that is passed
 * in through the  constructor and uses it in it's calculations.
 * @return the age in years.
 */
public int findAgeInYears(){
    Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    int tempMonth = (petMonth - 1);
    cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -petDay);
    cal1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -(tempMonth));
    cal1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -petYear);
    ageInYears= (cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    return ageInYears;

}
/**
* This handy method findAgeInMonths() uses a gregorian calendar to give me the value     for the age of the animal in months. It uses the aPetMonth variable that is passed
* in through the  constructor and uses it in it's calculations.
* @return the age in months.
*/
public int findAgeInMonths(){
    Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    int tempMonth = (petMonth - 1);
    cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -petDay);
    cal1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -(tempMonth));
    cal1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -petYear);
    ageInMonths = (cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    return ageInMonths;
}
/**
* This handy method findAgeInDays() uses a gregorian calendar to give me the value for the age of the animal in days. It uses the aPetDay variable that is passed
* in through the  constructor and uses it in it's calculations.
* @return the age in days.
*/
public int findAgeInDays(){
    Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    int tempMonth = (petMonth - 1);
    cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -petDay);
    cal1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -(tempMonth));
    cal1.add(Calendar.YEAR, -petYear);
    ageInDays = (cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    return ageInDays;
}

}
```

Animal Class:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

/**
* This is the generic super class animal witch will be inherited by 
* each individual animal. It contains generic instance variables and methods.
* 
* @author Group 5 Tuesday 
*
*/
public class Animal {


private String name, trait, ageEffect;
private Gender gender;
private DateOfBirth dateOfBirth;
private int happy, hungry, energy, weight, hygiene, age, thirst;

/**
 * This is the constructor for the animal class. It initialises all the instance 
 * variables for the animal class.
 * @param aName - The name of the animal
 * @param aTrait - The trait of the animal
 * @param aWeight - the weight of the animal
 * @param aDateOfBirth - the date of birth of the animal
 */
public Animal (String aName,Gender aGender ,String aTrait, int aWeight, DateOfBirth aDateOfBirth, String aAgeEffect)
{

    name = aName;
    gender = aGender;
    dateOfBirth = aDateOfBirth;
    age = 2014 - dateOfBirth.getYear(); 
    trait = aTrait;
    happy = 500;
    energy = 500;
    hungry = 500;
    weight = aWeight;
    hygiene = 500;
    thirst = 500;
    ageEffect = aAgeEffect;
}



// getter and setter methods

/**
 * This method returns the animal name
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return the gender of the animal
 */
public Gender getGender()
{
    return gender;
}
/**
 * This method returns the trait of the animal
 * @return the Trait
 */
public String getTrait() {
    return trait;
}
/**
 * This method returns the Age effect of the animal
 * @return the Age Effect
 */
public String getAgeEffect() {
    return ageEffect;
}
/**
 * This method returns the happiness of the animal
 * @return the happy stat
 */
public int getHappy() {
    return happy;
}
/**
 * This method returns the hungry statistic of the animal
 * @return the hungry
 */
public int getHungry() {
    return hungry;
}
/**
 * This method returns the Energy statistic of the animal
 * @return the energy
 */
public int getEnergy() {
    return energy;
}
/**
 * This method returns the Weight statistic of the animal
 * @return the weight
 */
public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
/**
 * This method returns the Hygiene statistic of the animal
 * @return the hygiene
 */
public int getHygiene() {
    return hygiene;
}
/**
 * This method returns the age of the animal
 * @return the age
 */
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
/**
 * This method returns the Thirst statistic of the animal
 * @return the thirst
 */
public int getThirst()
{
    return thirst;
}


/**
 * This method it used to change the Name of the animal
 * @param nName - the new name
 */
public void setName(String nName) {
    name = nName;
}

public void setGender(Gender nGender)
{
    gender = nGender;
}
/**
 * This method it used to change the trait of the animal
 * @param nTrait- the new trait of the animal
 */
public void setTrait(String nTrait) {
    trait = nTrait;
}
/**
 * This method it used to change the age effect of the animal
 * @param nAgeEffect - the new age affect of the animal
 */
public void setAgeEffect(String nAgeEffect) {
    ageEffect = nAgeEffect;
}
/**
 * This method it used to change the happy statistic  of the animal
 * @param nHappy - the new happy statistic of the animal
 */
public void setHappy(int nHappy) {
    happy = nHappy;
    if (happy > 500) {happy = 500;}
    if (happy < 0 ){happy = 0;}
}
/**
 * This method it used to change the hungry statistic  of the animal
 * @param nHungry the new hungry statistic of the animal
 */
public void setHungry(int nHungry) {
    hungry = nHungry;
    if (hungry > 500) {hungry = 500;}
    if (hungry < 0 ){hungry = 0;}
}
/**
 * This method it used to change the happy statistic  of the animal
 * @param nEnergy- the new energy statistic of the animal.
 */
public void setEnergy(int nEnergy) {
    energy = nEnergy;
    if (energy > 500) {energy = 500;}
    if (energy < 0 ){energy = 0;}
}
/**
 * This method it used to change the Weight statistic  of the animal
 * @param nWeight - the new weight statistic of the animal
 */
public void setWeight(int nWeight) {
    weight = nWeight;
}
/**
 * This method it used to change the Hygiene statistic  of the animal
 * @param nHygiene - the new hygiene statistic of the animal
 */
public void setHygiene(int nHygiene) {
    hygiene = nHygiene;
    if (hygiene > 500) {hygiene = 500;}
    if (hygiene < 0 ){hygiene = 0;}
}
/**
 * This method it used to change the age of the animal
 * @param nAge - the animals new age
 */
public void setAge(int nAge) {
    age = nAge;
}
/**
 * This method is used to change the thirst statistic of the animal
 * @param nThirst - the animals new thirst statistic
 */
public void setThirst(int nThirst)
{
    thirst = nThirst;
    if (thirst > 500) {thirst = 500;}
    if (thirst < 0 ){thirst = 0;}
}
/**
 * This method will be used by the end user to interact with the animal. 
 * Playing with the animal will make it happy
 */
public void play() 
{
    happy = happy + 50;
    energy = energy - 50;
    weight = weight - 5;
}

/**
 * This method will be used by the end user to interact with the animal.
 * cleaning the animal will increase it's hygiene. but will make it more unhappy
 */
public void clean()
{
    hygiene = hygiene + 50;
    happy = happy - 25;
}

/**
 * This method will be used by the end user to interact with the animal.
 * Feeding the animal will make it less hungry
 */
public void feed()
{
    System.out.println("You have fed " + name);
    hungry = hungry + 50;
}

/**
 * This method will be used by the end user to interact with the animal.
 * Giving the animal a drink will increase the thirst variable.
 */
public void drink()
{
    thirst = thirst + 50;
}

/**
 * This method will be used by the end user to interact with the animal.
 * Letting the animal sleep will increase it's energy
 */
public void sleep()
{
    System.out.println(name + " is now sleeping");
    energy = energy + 50;
}

/**
 * This method will be called if the animal's energy drops below a certain level
 * If an animal passes out it's energy will increase but it's happiness will decrease a lot
 */
public void passOut()
{
    System.out.println(name + " has passed out from being to tired");
    happy = happy - 50;
    energy = energy + 25;
}

public void Death()
{
    System.out.println("Your animal has now died");
}

public void runAway()
{
    System.out.println("Your animal has run away because of you poor care");
}


}
```

Main method:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CatInterface_Tester  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat_Interface myInterface = new Cat_Interface(null);}

}
```

Finally, it gives me this error when I run the interface:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Cat_Interface.<init>(Cat_Interface.java:75)
```

Comment: Use a model to link the various elements of ui, change the model as required and update the ui to represent the state of the UI

Comment: @MadProgrammer: even better than my suggestions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Feel free to fill out...typing it out on the ipad makes me cringe :P

Comment: This question doesn't have much to do with progress bars.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you're seeing an error: `"The cat.getHappy() that I am referencing seems to pull up an error"` --then please post the error message. For all we know, your cat variable could be null, and you could be getting a NullPointerException.
2. The cat variable should most definitely not be static.
3. To have outside classes change the state of this class, give this class a public method that outside classes can call. In the method, then use the information passed in to set the JProgressBar's value property.
4. More code and more details will be needed to fully help you. Your current question is very sparse on this.

e.g.,

```
public void setProgress(int progress) {
  myProgressBar.setValue(progress);
}
```

---

**Edit**

The better answer is as per MadProgrammer -- try to separate your GUI, also known as the "view" from your business data, AKA your "model" by using a Model-View-Control type of architecture. If you go this route, your view will have listeners added to the model, either directly or indirectly through the control, so that it is notified if the model changes state, and so it can then change its presentation of the data. This is a little bit of a more advanced programming concept, and if you are just starting out, may be over-kill, but it is effective and definitely aids later when you need to debug your app or want to improve it.

---

**Edit 2**
You have verified that your exception is a NPE. This is due to the cat variable being null. The solution: don't try to call methods on null variables but instead try to assign it a valid reference first. This may be as simple as:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
```

---

**Edit 3**

1. Get the Cat_Interface variable outside of the Cat class. It has no business being in there.
2. Your current code passes a null into the Cat_Interface class, assigns this to the Cat variable. So you should not be surprised to see a NPE because you're trying to call a method on a variable **that you explicitly set to null**! Don't do this.
3. If all the main method does is to create the Cat_Interface object and display it, then let this class do all. Don't pass in a Cat into its constructor but rather have it create its own Cat instance and use it.

Comment: I have added the different classes that I am using and also the error message I get. Thanks for the tips also!

Comment: @user3521306: yep it's a NullPointerException or NPE, just as I suspected.

Comment: @user3521306: see edit 2.

Comment: Wouldn't referencing the Cat class in that way mean I'd have to have the interface class extend the Cat class and then have to invoke the Cat constructor?

Comment: @user3521306: yes that is correct.

Comment: So I added this to the Cat class.

Comment: Cat_Interface cat = new Cat_Interface(this);

Then added this to the Cat_Interface class:
public Cat_Interface(Cat cat)

Now it's telling me the super constructor Cat() is undefined!

Comment: @user3521306: no, I misread your previous comment. Yes, it would mean invoking the Cat Constructor, and ***no*** the interface should ***not*** extend Cat. In no way. That would be a gross misuse of inheritance. If you want to pass a Cat instance into the interface, then do so, but never have the GUI extend the model.

Comment: Got it working with the cat object now, finally.

Comment: Still getting thrown a null pointer when referencing the getHappy() method, though. Strange stuff.

Comment: @user3521306: Again, make sure that your GUI is not extending Cat -- is it? Next, show your latest code, including your main method and all error messages.

Comment: Updated the code there. No, the Cat class is not being extended. Added the main method (which is really just an interface call, for now.)
The only error, still, is the null pointer which has already been posted. This error occurs ANY time I reference the cat.get methods.

Comment: @user3521306: see **Edit 3**